how to implement a main table and subform-like tables with react
I am new to JS react framework. My application will list the projects when the web page is loaded, then user could select one or many projects, then make API calls to get the product orders related with that project.
I have Projects components, which create a html table, each row will be a project. When a project row is clicked, I could use the project ID to make API call. once the API response for the product orders is received, how will these product order data be passed to ProductOrders components?
also will the web page have an empty div (place holder) for ProductOrders, then when the ProductOrders data is in, it gets refreshed?
In jQuery, I could use the response data to construct productorders html and append or replace existing web elements.  In React, I have no idea how to achieve that.
